# How to create fast trigger which removes trailing spaces

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I tried to create trigger which removes trailing spaces. To speet it up I specified that it shoudl execute only if column actually contains leading space:

```
create table rid (nimetus varchar(50));
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION public.TrimRid() RETURNS trigger AS $$
    BEGIN
        NEW.nimetus:= TRIM(trailing from NEW.nimetus);
        RETURN NEW;
    END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER rid_trim_trig BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF nimetus
   ON rid WHEN (NEW.nimetus like '% ') EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.TrimRid();
```

This code throws error

```
ERROR:  statement trigger's WHEN condition cannot reference column values
LINE 10:    ON rid WHEN (NEW.nimetus like '% ') EXECUTE PROCEDURE pub...
                         ^
SQL state: 42P17
Character: 304
```

How to create fast trigger for removing trailing spaces in Postgres ?

Comment: `' '` is not required. It is by default. If when clause is removed, it works without `' '`

Comment: Try `CREATE TRIGGER ... ON rid FOR EACH ROW WHEN ...`

Comment: It worked, thank you. You may wrote this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when not specified, trigger created as statement level trigger. However using row columns in the `WHERE` clause is possible for row level triggers only.

So the trigger creation statement should to contain `FOR EACH ROW` clause:

```
CREATE TRIGGER rid_trim_trig
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF nimetus ON rid
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (NEW.nimetus like '% ') EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.TrimRid();
```

More in the [CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) doc.